# Update multiple rows in a table with one SQL statement with a computed value per row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I have a scenario whereby I have a table of data I wish to import into my schema. The key field on the import t\ble AND my target table is a field called `MEMBERNO`

Before importing, I check if any of the rows in the import table have a `MEMBERNO` that currently exists within the target table. If so, I wish to amend the `MEMBERNO` on the import table to the next available value before starting the import (a simple `INSERT INTO targetTable SELECT * FROM importTable`)

The next available MEMBERNO is currently identified by adding 1 to `SELECT MAX(MEMBERNO) FROM targetTable` - can I apply this function to several rows in one SQL statement or will I have to create a cursor to loop through? Ideally, I would like to have one UPDATE statement where the value to set is "moving" but I'm not sure this is possible

So something like...

```
UPDATE importTable SET MEMBERNO = nextavailablenumber 
   WHERE MEMBERNO IN (SELECT MEMBERNO FROM targetTable)
```

where nextAvailableNumber is computed for each `UPDATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to do the update, you can do the check and alter the `MemberNo` all within the insert to the Target table

```
INSERT TargetTable (MemberNo, Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT  MemberNo = CASE WHEN t.MemberNoExists IS NULL THEN i.MemberNo
                        ELSE n.NextMemberNo + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.MemberNoExists ORDER BY i.MemberNo)
                    END,
        i.Column1,
        i.Column2,
        i.Column3
FROM    ImportTable i
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 MemberNoExists = 1
            FROM    TargetTable t
            WHERE   t.MemberNo = i.MemberNo
        ) t
        CROSS JOIN 
        (   SELECT  NextMemberNo = MAX(MemberNo) 
            FROM    TargetTable
        ) n;
```

The subquery `t` simply generates 1 when the MemberNo already exists, and NULL when it doesn't. If it doesn't exist then the MemberNo from the import table is used.

The subquery `n` gets the maximum `MemberNo` in the target table. This is only used where the MemberNo from the import table already exists. Then, so that you don't need a loop it uses `ROW_NUMBER` to increment this maximum MemberNo by one for each new row to avoid duplicates.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5add1/2)** *(Only with SELECT for demonstration purposes)*

If you do still need to do the update you can use a similar query:

```
WITH Import AS
(   SELECT  NewMemberNo = n.NextMemberNo + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.MemberNo),
            i.MemberNo
    FROM    ImportTable i
            CROSS JOIN 
            (   SELECT  NextMemberNo = MAX(MemberNo) 
                FROM    TargetTable
            ) n
    WHERE   EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    TargetTable t
                WHERE   t.MemberNo = i.MemberNo
            ) 
)
UPDATE  Import
SET     MemberNo = NewMemberNo;
```

**[UPDATE example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5add1/5)**

Comment: thanks @GarethD - I will use the update as I need to get it into a bit of dynamic SQL but that approach is very useful to me and has shown me a trick or two I can use going forward in so many scenarios! Thanks again!